# How can I convert time in string into a datetime format so that I can get difference between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with two columns with different times in string format, I want to find the difference between the two columns so I use the following code

```
operational_data_clean['Pick/pack start-time'] = pd.to_datetime(operational_data_clean['Pick/pack start-time'])

operational_data_clean['Flight launched-time'] = pd.to_datetime(operational_data_clean['Flight launched-time'])

operational_data_clean['time_to_launch'] = 0

operational_data_clean['time_to_launch'] = operational_data_clean['Flight launched-time'] - operational_data_clean['Pick/pack start-time']
```

but this code when I run the first time I get good results but when I run the second time it add todays date on the 'Pick/pack start-time' and 'Flight launched-time' value.

How can I convert this time only to hours without getting the dates that are messing my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are running your code with jupyter notebook.

When you execute your code, your variable `operational_data_clean['Pick/pack start-time']` becomes `pd.to_datetime(operational_data_clean['Pick/pack start-time'])`.

So when you execute the block one more time, jupyter remembers your variables and therefore will perform the same function again, essentially doing this:
`pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(operational_data_clean['Pick/pack start-time']))`.

As for `pd.to_datetime()` itself, I would advise to look through the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).